# Rails Devise Registrations redirects user after a couple of failed trials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a devise registrations_controller whose create method redirects the user after a couple of trials. The trouble is I am using the same create method for a dedicated  registrations page and a lightbox registration. The lightbox calls the create method using an ajax call and the redirection is creating trouble.

I haven't done much in  the create method other than calling super. How do I tell devise not to redirect if an ajax call made to it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the redirect, you can build a custom failure app:

```
 class CustomFailureApp < Devise::FailureApp

  def respond    
    unless request.format.to_sym == :html
      http_auth
    else
      redirect_to redirect_url
   end
    end

   def http_auth 
      super     
      self.status         = 401
      self.content_type   = 'json'
      self.response_body  = {
        :error => 'NO MORE REDIRECT',
        :status => 401
      }.to_json
  end
end
```

Configure Warden to use this failure app in the devise initializer:

```
    Devise.setup do |config|

  ...

  # ==> Warden configuration
  # If you want to use other strategies, that are not (yet) supported by Devise,
  # you can configure them inside the config.warden block.
  config.warden do |manager|
    manager.failure_app = CustomFailureApp
  end
end
```

Here's a reference:

http://casperfabricius.com/site/2010/09/30/ajax-sign-in-and-sign-up-with-devise/